# How to query data in a flattened Firebase structure?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire, nosql

I'm trying to create database for a real estate agency with Firebase. I decide to create a flatten database but I need some help..
(I'm using AngularJS)

Here is a sample of the database :

```
  "city" : {
    "Montpellier" : {
      "xx2" : true,
      "xx3" : true
    },
    "Teyran" : {
      "xx1" : true
    }
  },
  "owners" : {
    "xxx1" : {
      "lastname" : "Duparc",
      "name" : "Jean"
    },
    "xxx2" : {
      "lastname" : "Dupont",
      "name" : "Henry"
    },
    "xxx3" : {
      "lastname" : "Wood",
      "name" : "John"
    }
  },
  "prices" : {
    "xxx1" : 405000,
    "xxx2" : 100000,
    "xxx3" : 122000
  },
  "type" : {
    "appartment" : {
      "xx2" : true
    },
    "home" : {
      "xx1" : true
    },
    "land" : {
      "xx3" : true
    }
  }
```

XX1, XX2, XX3 is the refs for each product.

In this database we see that in node Type, there is :

- one home(house) : XX1
- one apartment : XX2
- one land : XX3

The question is : What if I want to list each product with type : Apartment?

Then if I'm able to get the ref of each Apartment, how can I construct the details for this product ?

I mean how can I get the name, last name of the owners, price, city, etc ?

Answer (score 1):

What you've shown in your data structure are the indexes.

You'll typically also have a list with the master copy for each property:

```
"properties": {
  "xx1": {
    "city": "Teyran",
    "owner": "Jean Duparc",
    "price": 405000,
    "type": "home",
  },
  "xx2": {
    "city": "Montpellier",
    "owner": "Henry Dupont",
    "price": 100000,
    "type": "apartment",
  },
  "xx3": {
    "city": "Montpellier",
    "owner": "John Wood",
    "price": 122000,
    "type": "land",
  }
}
```

Now with our indexes and the above structure, you can for example look up the apartments with:

```
ref.child('type').child('apartment').on('value', function(keys) {
  keys.forEach(function(keySnapshot) {
    ref.child('properties').child(keySnapshot.ref().key()).once('value', function(propertySnapshot) {
      console.log(propertySnapshot.val());
    });
  });
})
```

To update a property, you'd use a [multi-location update](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2015-10-07-how-to-keep-your-data-consistent.html). For example to update the owner of `xx1`:

```
var updates = {};
updates['/properties/xx1'] = property;
updates['/owners/Jean Duparc/'+id] = null;
updates['/owners/Runfast Webmaster/'+id] = true;
ref.update(updates);
```

Comment: Franck, I get this error : TypeError: keySnapshot.key is not a function. (In 'keySnapshot.key()', 'keySnapshot.key' is undefined)

Comment: Typo: `keySnapshot().ref().key()`. Note that Firebase has pretty decent [reference documentation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/) to help you with this type of stuff too.

Comment: I take a look at the ref documentation already. But I didn't found anything about the error : TypeError: keySnapshot is not a function. (In 'keySnapshot()', 'keySnapshot' is an instance of R)

Comment: Frank, I have a similar flattened data structure {key1:true,key2:true} and I'm looking for the most efficient way to call a query that returns the set of objects related to the keys from within Swift. Has this changed significantly with the new release? Any assistance is appreciated.